# While using react-router 5 with redux 7 react-router <Link> is not resetting state after going to new route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using the following versions:

```
`"react-router": "^5.2.0",`
`"react-router-domreact-router": "^5.2.0",`
```

Not sure if my current setup is React-router 5 friendly or not, I was using a version prior to v5 before this.

The problem in this example is with `<Route component={withTracker(InterviewContainer)} path="/interviews/companies/:companyId" />` and `<Link/>`

**Here's my scenario:**

1. Home page loads with a list of company links
2. Click on a company `<Link />` which routes me to `/interviews/companies/:companyId`
3. Page loads fine, I see images, etc. for that particular company
4. Click browser's Back button
5. Click on a different company `<Link />` that points to a different companyId
6. **Problem**: for #5, when the company page initially loads, it's loading with stale images and data for some reason.  So in other words, I'm seeing the previous company's data & images from step #2 briefly until my React hook makes a new call to get data for this new CompanyId and repaints the browser with the right data (data for the companyId represented in the new route)

**index.tsx** (note the use of **BrowserRouter** here)

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
//...more code and then:

render(
    <>
        <div className="Site">
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <App />
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        </div>
        <Footer />
    </>,
);
```

**App.ts**

```
import { Route, RouteComponentProps, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

...more code and then here are my routes:

<Switch>
    <Route component={withTracker(HomePageContainer)} exact path="/" />
    <Route
        path="/companies/:companyId/details"
        render={(props: RouteComponentProps<{ companyId: string }>) => (
            <CompanyDetailContainer {...props} fetchCompanyNew={fetchCompanyNew} httpRequest={Request} useFetchCompany={useFetchCompany} />
        )}
    />
    <Route component={withTracker(InterviewContainer)} path="/interviews/companies/:companyId" />
    <Route component={withTracker(About)} path="/about" />
    <Route component={withTracker(Container)} path="/" />
    <Route component={withTracker(NotFound)} path="*" />
</Switch>
```

**Here is how the company Link is coded:**

**Note**:  I am using **Redux** State
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",

**InterviewContainer.tsx** (the parent that does the company fetching)

```
class InterviewContainer extends Component<PropsFromRedux & RouteComponentProps<{ companyId: string }>> {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { fetchCompany } = this.props;
        const { companyId } = this.props.match.params;
        fetchCompany(companyId);
    }
    
    render() {
        const { company } = this.props;
        return (company && <Interview className="ft-interview" company={company} />) || null;
    }
}

const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
    company: state.company.company,
});

const mapDispatch = {
    fetchCompany: fetchCompanyFromJSON,
};

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch);

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;
export default withRouter(connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(InterviewContainer));
```

**LinkItem.tsx** (one of the children rendered by `InterviewContainer` and receives the company from `InterviewContainer`)

```
render() {
    const { company } = this.props,
        uri = company.notInterviewed ? `companies/${company.id}/details` : `/interviews/companies/${company.id}`,
        className = `margin-top-10 margin-bottom-10 ${company.notInterviewed ? 'ft-company-not-interviewed' : ''}`;
    const link = (
        <Link className={className} id={company.id.toString()} to={uri}>
            <span id="company-name">{company.name}</span>
        </Link>
    );
}
```

**I think I may have to reset Redux state on route change**.  I see people in the past have used `LOCATION_CHANGE` but that's outdated and that's a constant provided by third party redux libs that are no longer supported.  So not sure how to do that with Redux v7+

So I think I just **need a way to detect a location change** and then somehow **update my react store to reset company** (set `company: state.company.company,` to undefined from my redux action)

Answer (score 0):

I know things like this can be cumbersome. Have you tried passing in state with the Link as `<Link to={uri} state={...someState} />`. Then wherever it is loading it should rerender or reset props according to that. Maybe throw some skeleton loaders or conditional rendering logic.

Comment: I have never seen state passed through a <Link />.  I simply pull the companyId from route props `this.props.match.params;` and fetch the company data in my React Hook.  It's not that it's not re-rendering, it's that on initial render it's somehow showing stale company data.  I do not see anything in code causing this so it has to be something with react-router and browser history is my guess

Comment: heck yeah. I love useParams and this.props.match.params for the same fact. The state is declarative and does not change on rerender or even refresh. Sometimes it may not be the best solution when you want ot use either params or local state to do something else with your props. To sum params over state everyday.

Comment: Also to pass state I pulled the code from documentation it is ```<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>```

i find it usefult when i want some of the state from current props to pass to new history object. I am almost certain <Link /> is just history.push and <Redirect /> is history.replace.

Comment: just seems hacky to me, sorry. I shouldn't have to do anything fancy to fix this Link problem IMO

Comment: I should add that I'm using redux.  And I searched and thee must be some way to reset a redux state other than using `LOCATION_CHANGE` which comes from special redux-router libs that are obsolete now

Comment: please delete your answer, I have an answer to this that I will add